# AngularJS executing a function asynchronously

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, async-await

I have a controller that passes execution to a factory -- controller.getCustomerById -> factory.getCustomerByID. In this case, the factory function is posting and retrieving data via MVC/angular.$http.post. That all works fine but the subsequent actions in my controller function are executing before the .post is finished.

I've tried making either or both async/await but I think I'm not understanding how to do that. I've tried quite a few of the examples here and elsewhere with no luck.

I have a button that calls setOrderFromGrid which calls getCustomerById. I would assume that making controller.getCustomerById an async function would be the best way but I can't get it to work.

```
angular.module('aps').factory('TechSheetFactory', 
function($http) {
    return {
        //The ajax that is called by our controller
        ITS: function(onSuccess, onFailure) {
            const rvtoken = $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();
            $http({
                method: "post",
                url: "/DesktopModules/MVC/TechSheetMaint/TechSheet/InitializeNew",
                headers: {
                    "ModuleId": moduleId,
                    "TabId": tabId,
                    "RequestVerificationToken": rvtoken
                }
            }).then(onSuccess).catch(onFailure);
        },


        saveTechSheetAng: function(onSuccess, onFailure, techSheetInfo) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(techSheetInfo));
            const rvtoken = $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();
            $http.post("/DesktopModules/MVC/TechSheetMaint/TechSheet/SaveTechSheetAng",
                JSON.stringify(techSheetInfo),
                {
                    headers: {
                        "ModuleId": moduleId,
                        "TabId": tabId,
                        "RequestVerificationToken": rvtoken,
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                }).then(onSuccess).catch(onFailure);
        } ,

        getCustomerById: function(onSuccess, onFailure, customerSearchString) {
            alert('factory getcustomerbyid: ' + customerSearchString);
            const rvtoken = $("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val();
            $http.post("/DesktopModules/MVC/TechSheetMaint/TechSheet/GetCustomerById",
                {custId:customerSearchString},
                {
                    headers: {
                        "ModuleId": moduleId,
                        "TabId": tabId,
                        "RequestVerificationToken": rvtoken,
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                }).then(onSuccess).catch(onFailure);
        }


    };
});

angular.module('aps').controller('TechSheetCtl', ['TechSheetFactory','$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$interval', '$modal', '$log','uiGridConstants', 
function (TechSheetFactory,$scope, $rootScope, $http, $interval, $modal, $log) {


/* -----------------SaveTechSheet ------------*/
    $scope.saveTechSheet = function() {
        if (!$scope.dvTechSheet.$valid) {
            $scope.Message = "Form not complete.";
            $scope.Status = false;
            $scope.showErrors=true;
            return;
        }
        alert($scope.TechSheetInfo.Customer.CustomerID);
        if (JSON.stringify($scope.TechSheetInfo.Customer) !== JSON.stringify($scope.TechSheetInfoStatic.Customer) &&
            $scope.TechSheetInfo.Customer.CustomerID !== 0) {
            if (confirm("You've made changes to this Customer. Save them?") !== true) {
                return;
            }
        }

        if (JSON.stringify($scope.TechSheetInfo.WorkOrder) !== JSON.stringify($scope.TechSheetInfoStatic.WorkOrder) &&
            $scope.TechSheetInfo.WorkOrder.WorkOrderID !== 0) {
            if (confirm("You've made changes to this Work Order. Save them?") !== true) {
                return;
            }
        }
        successFunction = function(response) {
            var data = response.data.Data;
            alert(data);
            var techSheet = data.techSheet;
            alert(data.status);
            if (data.status) {
                alert("looks good");
                $scope.Message = "";
                $scope.showErrors = false;
                $scope.TechSheetInfo = techSheet;
                alert($scope.TechSheetInfo);
                $scope.TechSheetInfoStatic = angular.copy(techSheet);
                $rootScope.customerInfo = techSheet.Customer;
                createpdf($scope);
            } else {
                if (response.message !== null) {
                    $scope.Status = datae.status;
                    $scope.showErrors = true;
                    $scope.Message = data.message;
                }
            }
        };

        failureFunction = function(data) {
            console.log('Error' + data);
        };

        TechSheetFactory.saveTechSheetAng(successFunction, failureFunction,$scope.TechSheetInfo);
    };
/* ----------End SaveTechSheet ---------*/

//------------Initialize a new tech sheet. This is the default action for the page load/refresh/discard changes/clear form
    $scope.initializeTechSheet = function() {
        $scope.TechSheetInfo = [];
        $scope.TechSheetInfoStatic = [];
        $scope.customerIDDisabled = false;
        $scope.orderIDDisabled = false;
        $rootScope.customerInfo = [];
        $scope.WindowsPassword = "";
        $scope.EmailPassword = "";

        const successFunction = function(response) {
            $scope.TechSheetInfo = response.data;
            $rootScope.customerInfo = response.data.Customer;
            $scope.TechSheetInfoStatic = angular.copy(response.data);
        };

        const failureFunction = function(response) {
            //console.log('Error' + response.status);
        };

        TechSheetFactory.ITS(successFunction, failureFunction);
    };
//end initializeTechSheet

    $scope.getCustomerById =  function(custId) {
        const successFunction = function(response) {
            alert("success");
            $scope.TechSheetInfo.Customer = response.data;
            $scope.TechSheetInfoStatic.Customer = angular.copy(response.data);
            $rootScope.customerInfo = response.data;
            $scope.customerIDDisabled = true;
        };
        const failureFunction = function(data) {
            alert('getcustomer fail');
            console.log('Error' + JSON.stringify(data));
        };

        TechSheetFactory.getCustomerById(successFunction, failureFunction, custId);

    };


    $scope.setOrderFromGrid = function(woInfo) {
        $scope.getCustomerById(woInfo.CustomerID);
        $scope.TechSheetInfo.WorkOrder = woInfo; //this line and the next are occurring before getCustomerById has completed
        $scope.TechSheetInfoStatic.Customer = angular.copy($scope.TechSheetInfo.Customer);
        $scope.orderIDDisabled=true;
        $scope.dvTechSheet.$setPristine();

    };

    $scope.resetForm = function() {
        if (!$scope.dvTechSheet.$pristine) {
            if (!confirm("Discard Changes?")) {
                return;
            }
        }
        $scope.initializeTechSheet();
        $scope.dvTechSheet.$setPristine();
    };


}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You lose the advantage of the Promises so you can opt-in a Promise this way. (I do not recommend it)
From the top of head something like this:

```
  // inject $q

  $scope.getCustomerById =  function(custId) {
    const deferred = $q.defer()
    const successFunction = function(response) {
        $scope.TechSheetInfo.Customer = response.data;
        $scope.TechSheetInfoStatic.Customer = angular.copy(response.data);
        $rootScope.customerInfo = response.data;
        $scope.customerIDDisabled = true;
        deferred.resolve(); // can pass value if you like
    };
    const failureFunction = function(data) {
        alert('getcustomer fail');
        console.log('Error' + JSON.stringify(data));
        deferred.reject();
    };

    TechSheetFactory.getCustomerById(successFunction, failureFunction, custId);
   return deferred.promise;
};
```

/////////////

```
$scope.setOrderFromGrid = function(woInfo) {
    const prom = $scope.getCustomerById(woInfo.CustomerID);
    prom.then(()=>{
       $scope.TechSheetInfo.WorkOrder = woInfo;
       $scope.TechSheetInfoStatic.Customer = 
       angular.copy($scope.TechSheetInfo.Customer);
       $scope.orderIDDisabled=true;
        $scope.dvTechSheet.$setPristine();
    })


};
```

Comment: And, that does it. So, what did you mean by "I do not recommend it"? This approach?